# If sequence ${s_n}$ converges, then sequence ${|s_n|}$ converges as well

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

**My idea:**

$\{s_n\}$ converges to the point $s$ and it means, that $\{s_n\}$ is Cauchy . Then for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$, such that if $m,n >N$ implies $|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon $. It means, that $\{s_n\}$ and $\{s_m\}$ converges to the point $s$.

Then exist $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that for $n>N_1$ and $n>N_2$, we have $|s_n-s|<\epsilon/2 $ and $|s_m-s|<\epsilon/2 $

We have to show, that $\{|s_n|\}$ converges to $s$ as well.
$$|s_n - s_m| \le |s_n - s|  +  |s_n - s| $$
by triangle inequality.
But we know, that $|s_n - s|$ and $|s_n - s|$ are less than $\epsilon/2$.

If we take absolute value of $\epsilon/2$ it is still equal to $\epsilon/2$.
Hence sequence $\{|s_n|\}$ is Cauchy and converges.

Is my proof correct? if yes, is it well written or I should add something?
If wrong, where did I do the mistake?

Comment: I'm wondering if you've made some typos, because your explanations don't seem to match up with your claims. Also, I feel you shouldn't need to appeal to Cauchy sequences, since by triangle inequality, ||s_n|-|s||≤|s_n-s|<ε

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful: if $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = s$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} |s_n| = |s|$, not $s$.

What you must show is $\big||s_n| - |s|\big| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, not $\big||s_n - s|\big| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$.

Also, we can prove it directly, without using Cauchy sequences:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. There exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_0 \implies |s_n - s| < \varepsilon$

For $n \geq n_0$ by the reverse triangle inequality we obtain:

$$\big||s_n| - |s|\big|\leq |s_n - s| < \varepsilon$$

The reverse triangle inequality is this:

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:
>   $$\big||x|-|y|\big| \leq |x - y|$$
>   Proof:
>   $$|x| = |(x - y) + y| \leq |x-y| + |y| \implies |x|-|y| \le |x-y|$$
>   $$|y| = |(y - x) + x| \leq |x-y| + |x| \implies |x|-|y| \ge -|x-y|$$
>   Thus $|x|-|y| \in \big[-|x-y|, |x-y|\big]$ which means $\big||x|-|y|\big| \leq |x - y|$.

Comment: Now it's clear for me! Didn't know about triangle inequality.
Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a straightforward application of the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

If $s_n$ converges to $a$ then $|s_n - a| < \varepsilon$ for $n$ big enough, and so $$|\, |s_n|-|a| \,| \leq |s_n - a| < \varepsilon,$$
from which we obtain  that $|s_n|$ converges to $|a|$.